# Regex on a directory on Linux and Windows

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to check if a directory represented as a String contains as a substring one of the following strings

```
  \.. OR ..\ OR /.. OR ../
```

however the following code :

```
 System.out.println("C:\\mytext.zip".matches(".*(\\..|..\\|/..|../).*"));
```

gives true instead of false,where can be the problem in the regex?

Comment: You should escape all the dots and backslashes. `\\\.\.|\.\.\\|/\.\.|\.\./` string pattern, in Java, it will look like `".*(?:\\\\\\.\\.|\\.\\.\\\\|/\\.\\.|\\.\\./).*"`

Comment: `Path path = Paths.get("...");` and then `path.normalize()` would eliminate `..` so you can check for String equality. Normal security usage is to see that the path does not leave the boxed directory for files. (Also `toAbsolutePath`)